# How to get full path of the uploaded file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeIgniter file uploading class example https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html  to upload files. In the example after i uploaded files it will show details like below in the upload success view page.

```
 Array
(
[upload_data] => Array
    (
        [file_name] => VenkataKrishna10.pdf
        [file_type] => application/pdf
        [file_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/upload/application/
        [full_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/upload/application/VenkataKrishna10.pdf
        [raw_name] => VenkataKrishna10
        [orig_name] => VenkataKrishna.pdf
        [client_name] => VenkataKrishna.pdf
        [file_ext] => .pdf
        [file_size] => 83.27
        [is_image] => 
        [image_width] => 
        [image_height] => 
        [image_type] => 
        [image_size_str] => 
    )

 )
```

Afterwards I tried to see entire uploaded data in an array format. My question is how to get full file path from the above array. I know there is a variable `full_path` but I am not able to get it. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try `$array['upload_data']['full_path']`?

Comment: I tried this one also giving error A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: array

Filename: controllers/upload.php

Line Number: 34

Comment: try `$data['upload_data']['full_path']` from controller and `$upload_data['full_path']` from view

Comment: nope it's giving error ............stating no index

Comment: thanks air4x..............you can write that one in answer i will accept it.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your controller use

```
echo $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
```

From your view use

```
echo $upload_data['full_path'];
```

Comment: hey i have another doubt i need to send this file as an attachment in mail for that i need to add this file path in $this->email->attach(); how should i write that.......

Comment: Use `$data['upload_data']['full_path']` if your code to send email is in controller. Else pass it as an argument to your model method, if your email sending code is there.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
                    // $data will contain full inforation
                    echo "Full path is:". $data['full_path'];

        }
```

Comment: wrong answer i can't down vote so lucky ..answer is $data['upload_data']['full_path']

Comment: It depends upon how you are storing the uploaded data. If you are simply storing like:  $data = $this->upload->data(); then access it by $data['full_path']; else if you are storing like $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); then access it by $data['upload_data']['full_path']. It's simple array working.

Comment: hey i have another doubt i need to send this file as an attachment in mail for that i need to add this file path in $this->email->attach(); how should i write that.......

Answer (score 1):

From you post, I am assuming that you have given output from print_r of some variable, say `$file_detail`.

If you want to get the full_path from `$file_detail`, you have to use

```
$file_detail['upload_data']['full_path']
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is returned upon succesful upload, you just need to retrieve the index key:

Controller:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
     $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
}
else
{
   $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload_data();
}
$this->load->view('myview', $data);
```

**myview.php**

```
<p>Full path: <?php echo $upload_data['full_path'];?></p>
```

Comment: i want to use that in controller and $data['full_path']; This is the error i am getting A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: full_path

Filename: controllers/upload.php

Line Number: 34

Comment: Are you sure the upload was succesful? Where are you trying to fetch the index? Could you post your actual code (not here in comments, though, just edit your question)?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete a file from uploads after inserting into database you can remove file from uploads using unlink($filename)

Comment: This does not appear to answer the poster's question.  They are asking how to get the full path from the files array; not how to delete the file.